# Update Server Component after data has been changed by Client Component in Next.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, next.js

I am still trying to wrap my head around this scenario. Can anyone please suggest what is the correct way to do this in Next.js 13?

I diplay a list of users in a Server Component, for example, like this (using MongoDB):

```js
// UsersList.jsx
const UsersList = () => {
  const users = await usersCollection.getUsers()

  return (
  <div>
    {users.map(user) => <div>{user}</div>}
  </div>
  )
}
```

And on the same page, I have also defined client component for adding users:

```js
// UsersEdit.jsx
'use client'
const UsersEdit = () => {
  const handleAdd() => // calls POST to /api/users
  return // render input + button
}
```

Both are displayed together like this in a Server Component Page:

```js
// page.jsx
const Users = () => {
  return (
  <div>
    <UsersList />
    <UsersEdit />
  </div>
  )
}
```

How should I "reload" or "notify" `UsersList` that a new user has been added to the collection to force it to display a new user/updated user?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The only way to update a Server Component is to reload the page. As it's sent to the browser as static HTML without any JavaScript attached to it to have interactivity.

To reload the page while keeping client side states, you could use [`router.refresh()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router#userouter), where `router` is the returned value by [`useRouter()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router). Here is an example working with a Todo List application:

> Let's consider a list view. Inside your Server Component, you fetch the list of items:

```js
// app/page.tsx

import Todo from "./todo";
async function getTodos() {
  const res = await fetch("https://api.example.com/todos", { cache: 'no-store' });
  const todos = await res.json();
  return todos;
}

export default async function Page() {
  const todos = await getTodos();
  return (
    <ul>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo} />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

> Each item has its own Client Component. This allows the component to use event handlers (like onClick or onSubmit) to trigger a mutation.

```
// app/todo.tsx

"use client";

import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useState, useTransition } from 'react';

export default function Todo(todo) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  // Create inline loading UI
  const isMutating = isFetching || isPending;

  async function handleChange() {
    setIsFetching(true);
    // Mutate external data source
    await fetch(`https://api.example.com/todo/${todo.id}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({ completed: !todo.completed }),
    });
    setIsFetching(false);

    startTransition(() => {
      // Refresh the current route and fetch new data from the server without
      // losing client-side browser or React state.
      router.refresh();
    });
  }

  return (
    <li style={{ opacity: !isMutating ? 1 : 0.7 }}>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={todo.completed}
        onChange={handleChange}
        disabled={isPending}
      />
      {todo.title}
    </li>
  );
}
```

⚠️: `refresh()` could re-produce the same result if [fetch requests are cached](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76204625/15288641). This is why that `cache: 'no-store'` on this example.

Answer (score 8):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75127011/17964403
This is Great for mutating on the client side but if you want to do something like search/filtering using input on the client side and want to re-fetch the same data you can do something like

```html
const [searchterm, setSearchterm] = useState("");
const handleSearch = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   if(!searchterm)return
   router.push(/home?search=`${searchterm}`)
}
```

and in the server component, you will receive the search param as a prop, see if the search param exists, if so then in the fetch call pass that and you will get filtered items.

Answer (score 2):

server rendering happens during the initial request. Once the HTML is generated and sent to the client, any updates or refreshes occur on the client side. The server does not have browser-related functionality, it just sends the HTML code without javascript. That is why as of now, if we want to refresh the page, we render a client-side component inside the server component and inside the client component we perform:

```
import {useRouter} from "next/navigation"

router.refresh()
```

If your app requires real-time updates, you should implement websocket communication. WebSocket communication can enable real-time bidirectional communication between the client and server, allowing for updates to be pushed from the server to the client without the need for manual page refreshes.

Answer (score -1):

I'd like to add something similar, which I guess someone need.

Suppose you have a login page, which is a client component. And you have a todolist page, which is a server component, to display the user's todo items.

If you switch from the login page to the todolist page, for example, you have completed the login.

Suppose you use "router.push('/todolist')" to jump, but sometimes the todolist may not refreshed, it shows the last user's todo items.

You can try this:

```
router.push(`/todolist?${Math.random().toString()}`);
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea, since instead of clearing the cache / auth cookies or whatever artefact persists last user's data, you're forcing a refresh (by changing the request path), which just hides the problem.