# NextJS refresh child Server component when updating parent Client component

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Following the pattern in docs for nesting server component inside client component, I get something like this.-

```
<Client>
    <Server />
</Client>
```

The idea is having interaction / state in `Client`, and once something change (for example a dropdownlist for filtering), the `Server` might reload to fetch data and refresh; intuitively I would have thought that rerendering `Client` would involve an automatic rerender on `Server`, but it's not happening, and can't find a straight forward way to pass a state props from `Client` to `Server`.

I'm guessing this should be a common scenario but can't find anything that fits in the docs, **is there a known pattern to solve this?**

Comment: A state update in a component won't re-render its children. This is normal React. Now about your issue, this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124513/update-server-component-after-data-has-changed-by-client-component-in-next-js