# how to render an async function from another file

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, backend

Using **Next.JS**.I will be building an admin panel dashboard for my web application. To retrieve the database, I utilized **Prisma client** and **MongoDB**.

I am unable to display the entire number of users that are in the database. I have to provide a count of all the users that are currently in the database. I tried rendering a separate function that I generated in my **db.ts** file on my **dashboard page**, but it isn't working.

Code :-

## **db.ts**

```
import { PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

declare global {
  var prisma: PrismaClient | undefined;
}

export const db = globalThis.prisma || new PrismaClient();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") globalThis.prisma = db;

export const userCount = async () => {
  try {
    const count = await db.user.count();
    console.log(count);
    return count;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error counting documents:", error);
    return null;
  }
};
```

## **admin/dashboard/page.tsx**

```
"use client";

import { userCount, db } from "@/lib/db";
import { Card, CardHeader, CardContent, CardTitle } from "@/components/ui/card";

const DashboardPage = () => {
  return (
    <Card className="w-full flex-col md:flex">
      <CardHeader>
        <p className="text-2xl font-semibold text-center">Dashboard</p>
      </CardHeader>

      <CardContent className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 xl:grid-cols-4 gap-4">
        <Card>
          <CardHeader className="flex flex-row items-center justify-between space-y-0 pb-2">
            <CardTitle className="text-sm font-medium">Total Users</CardTitle>
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              fill="none"
              stroke="currentColor"
              strokeLinecap="round"
              strokeLinejoin="round"
              strokeWidth="2"
              className="h-4 w-4 text-muted-foreground"
            >
              <path d="M12 2v20M17 5H9.5a3.5 3.5 0 0 0 0 7h5a3.5 3.5 0 0 1 0 7H6" />
            </svg>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardContent>
            <div className="text-2xl font-bold">{userCount()}</div>
            <p className="text-xs text-muted-foreground">
              +20.1% from last month
            </p>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default DashboardPage;
```

Problem - I need to render the user count on my dashboard page, therefore I created a function in db.ts called userCount. It isn't appearing.

Since **useEffect** is an async function, I tried using it, but it didn't work. It ought to display the overall number of users. If I console log the function in the **db.ts** file, it gives me the count, but not on the bashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

The `"use client"` forces your component's JS to run in the browser, where you do not have access to the database (`userCount()` will not run on the server, and then fail on the client).
As long as you do not need JS interactivity in that component, you can simply remove that line, and it will become a RSC ([React Server Component](https://vercel.com/blog/understanding-react-server-components)). **It will run on the server, and show the correct value**

If you later need to add JS interactivity (useState, useEffect, etc...), then you can split the component in two:

- a RSC that uses `userCount()` and provides the value a prop to the Client compoment
- a Client component that get `userCount: number` from its props, and use hooks (for exemple to update that value periodically)

---

See a more detailed explaition [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76947851/4345841) (about cookies, and how to split components between RSC and Client components)