# How to pass props or states from parent(child-component) to the child(server-component)?

Tags: parameter-passing, next.js13, server-side, client-side, viewpage

I have a server api call that requires user's ip address. for tracking the user, I am using a third party api.

Now, the problem that i'm mainly facing is, the client side codes cannot be loaded on the "view page source" tab. To fix this issue, i am planning to make another api call just to load the data on the server side. for this, i need to pass the ip address from client to server. I've found a solution for doing this from the nextjs's documentation on the url: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch

but i'm not sure about how to pass props to the children.

Let's say the "ServerComponent" is wrapped by a client-component named "ClientComponent"

```
<ClientComponent>
      <ServerComponent />
    </ClientComponent>
```

Also assume that this is my client component and the server-component is passing as it's(the client component's) {children}

```
'use client'

import { useState } from 'react'
 
export default function ClientComponent({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      {children}
    </>
  )
}
```

Now, I need to pass a prop or state ip:{userIp} from the ClientComponent to the ServerComponent.

I've found a nextjs 13 approach to use server-component inside a client component. doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/fetching-caching-and-revalidating#fetching-data-on-the-server-with-fetch

But I dont know how to pass props to this server-component

Comment: I think server component is dedicated to be static on client side. So you can not pass  props from client component. If you want update server component data you have to refresh the page.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124513/update-server-component-after-data-has-been-changed-by-client-component-in-next

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it won't matter if i refresh the page. I have to pass the prop anyhow and without that, it won't work.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this way for passing the props from parent to child component :

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import ServerComponent from './ServerComponent'; // Import the ServerComponent

export default function ClientComponent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const userIp = '...'; // Replace this with the user's IP address

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>{count}</button>
      <ServerComponent userIp={userIp} /> // pass props and states here 
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: but it isn't possible as the parent is client component and the child is server component. server component cannot be directly imported to client component.